# How to set the direction attribute for Scipy's solve_ivp routine?

Tags: python, scipy, attributes, numerical-integration

I would like to store only events that have a positive gradient using Scipy's solve_ivp; that is they are increasing with respect to the 0 solution. According to the documentation, this appears to be trackable by modifying the direction attribute under the events parameter. However, it's still unclear to me how to implement this so I would appreciate a working example.

My code is as follows:

````
def ivp_solver(system_of_equations: callable,  time_range: tuple, inital_cond: tuple, params: callable = morris_lecar_defaults(), track_event: callable = voltage_passes_threshold) -> object:```

    sol = solve_ivp(system_of_equations, time_range, inital_cond, args=(params,), events= track_event, t_eval= np.linspace(time_range[0], time_range[1],time_range[2]))
    return sol
````

This is the event I would like to track:

```
def voltage_passes_threshold(t, system_state, args):
   
    return system_state[0] +20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `voltage_passes_threshold.direction` to a positive value.  That is,

```
def voltage_passes_threshold(t, system_state, args):   
    return system_state[0] + 20

voltage_passes_threshold.direction = 1
```

Then the events recorded in `sol.t_events` and `sol.y_events` will be for events where `system_state[0]` *increases* through the value -20 (i.e. where `system_state[0] + 20` increases through 0).